# Probability of two sets being contained in a set $S$.

Tags: probability, probabilistic-method

I'm working on the following problem, and I'm afraid there is something fundamental I am not understanding.

> Let $s_1,\dots,s_m$ be independent random elements in $[n]$ not necessarily uniform or identically distributed; chosen with replacement, and let $S = \{s_1,\dots,s_m\}$. Let $I$ and $J$ be disjoint subsets of $[n]$. Prove that $$ P((I\cup J)\subseteq S) \leq P(I\subseteq S)P(J\subseteq S).$$

The event $I\cup J \subseteq S$ is the event that $I\subseteq S$ and $J\subseteq S$. But since $I$ and $J$ are disjoint, aren't these two events independent? If they are independent, doesn't that give us that
$$ P((I\cup J)\subseteq S) = P(I\subseteq S)P(J\subseteq S)$$
holds?

How can I proceed with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Disjoint (i.e. mutually exclusive) is not the same as independent

Comment: No, they aren't independent.  If we know that all the elements of $I$ have been chosen, it's less likely that all the elements of $J$ have been chosen isn't it?  Suppose $I$ and $j$ are the even elements and the odd elements, respectively.  Unless $S=[n]$, $\Pr(I\cup J \subseteq S) = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the error, consider the case where $n = 100$, $m = 10$, and $|I| = |J| = 10$. If $I \ \subset S$, what does this tell you about $J \subset S$? (The fact that it tells you *anything* is important.)

A hint for how to proceed: consider a conditional probability approach. Specifically: since $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \mathbb P(A) \cdot \mathbb P(B \mid A)$, we could say
$$\mathbb P((I \cup J) \subset S) = \mathbb P(I \subset S) \cdot \mathbb P(J \subset S \mid I \subset S).$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can, thank you so much. I feel a little silly now haha.

Comment: No need to feel silly! We've all been there!

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$ \mathbb{P}(I\cup J \subset S)=\mathbb{P}(I\subset S \wedge J\subset S) = \mathbb{P}(I\subset S | J\subset S) \mathbb{P} (J\subset S).$$
Now, if $J\subset S$, then at least $|J|$ of $m$ elements chosen were selected in $J$, and as $I$ and $J$ are disjoint there are then at most $m-|J|$ candidates to be selected from $I$. So $\mathbb{P}(I\subset S | J\subset S) \leq \mathbb{P}(I\subset S)$.